# customizing asp.net webforms site timeout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session-timeout

is it possible to set a user defined timeout value on an asp.net website...i have a table that stores the time out value for each user of my website...i need to set the time out based on who logged in...i know that the default aspnet timeout setting is 20 mins of inactivity...is there any way i can circumvent this...and yes i do need to show a modal when the timeout expires and need to reset the timeout value if the user wants to continue the session or log them out if they choose not to continue....
thanks in advance for any help on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session timeout setting is per application, so in your case to enforce different timeouts you will have to preemptively check how long since last request and abandon the session or in case where the user timeout is bigger that the application one, you will need to implement some type of keeplive functionality